# Custom Message/Template content using PHP and Mysql, Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'd like to create a message template in PHP but how can I load it into database and exectute it?

Sample Message

Hello #SUBSCRIBER_NAME#, We would like to inform you that your bill amounting #BILL_AMOUNT# is due on #DUE_DATE#, please pay on or before the specified date. Thank you.

Basically, the message content is editable but can use #SUBSCRIBER_NAME#, #DUE_DATE#, #BILL_AMOUNT# in PHP.

Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to my problem here is the code

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$string ="Hello #SUBSCRIBER_NAME#, We would like to inform you that your bill amounting #BILL_AMOUNT# is due on #DUE_DATE#, please pay on or before the specified date. Thank you.
";
echo str_replace(
    array("#SUBSCRIBER_NAME#","#BILL_AMOUNT#",'#DUE_DATE#'),
    array("Gegejosper", "1499", '06/30/2021'), $string);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel ? If not, update your question removing `laravel` and `laravel-blade`... If you are using laravel, then your answer is correct, but it is horrible, it should not be done like that in Laravel... There are layers to do this...